# Unknown publisher shown for a signed jar

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

I'm trying to deploy a jar using java web start technology.

Although I've signed the jar, when I run the jnlp file from the server I still get a warning the publisher is unknown.

Comment: My guess is you've used a *self*-signed certificate.

Comment: The file is signed using Thawte cert.

Comment: Where is the link to the apps. JNLP?